# matrix question in python with any module

Tags: python, matrix

alright lets say we have a matrix over here (m):
m <-- [[0, 0, 21, 35], [0, 0, 24, 40], [0, 0, 12, 20], [0, 0, 6, 10]]
i want to fill m2 which has double the length of columns by each digit for each number in m .
if the number is only a single digit we add "0" at the left for example if the number is 6 it becomes 06
this should be the finished result :
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '3', '5'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '3', '5'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '3', '5'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '3', '5']]
i was able to make it work by using .append but i want another method that can work algorithmically ( in my education sys using .append is forbidden )

Comment: If I understand ```[0, 0, 21, 35]``` result in ```['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '3', '5']``` so why ```[0, 0, 24, 40]``` is ```['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '3', '5']```

Comment: it was a typo sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**simple step by step solution to achieve the result:**

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 21, 35], [0, 0, 24, 40], [0, 0, 12, 20], [0, 0, 6, 10]]

resultant_matrix = []
# Iterate on the matrix for row
for matrix_row in matrix:
    new_row = []
    # Iterate on this row for value
    for value in matrix_row:
        # check if length ov value is 1, like 6
        if len(str(value)) == 1:
            # then we need to add 0,6 to our row
            new_row.extend((0,value))
        else:
            # else value is like 21 then add 2 and 1 to row
            value_str = str(value)
            value1, value2 = int(value_str[0]), int(value_str[1])
            new_row.extend((value1,value2))
    
    # append the new row to resultant matrix
    resultant_matrix.append(new_row)
    
print(resultant_matrix)
```

**Result:**

```
[
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 5], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

m = [
    [0, 0, 21, 35],
    [0, 0, 24, 40],
    [0, 0, 12, 20],
    [0, 0, 6, 10]
]

print([list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda i: str(i).zfill(2), row))) for row in m])
```

Output:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '1', '3', '5'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '4', '4', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '2', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '6', '1', '0']]
>>>
```

Comment: it seems that it works but i dont understand what have you done those function are new to me can you show le another way with basic python

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand but this may be solution.

```
[[int(x) for x in list(''.join([str(col).zfill(2) for col in row]))] for row in m]
```

Just transfer items of the matrix to sting and fill leading zeros fon one digit nubers. And then tranfer the items back to int (one by one).

**Update:**

```
m = [[0, 0, 21, 35], [0, 0, 24, 40], [0, 0, 12, 20], [0, 0, 6, 10]]
m2 = []

for i in range(len(m)):
  row = m[i]
  new_row = []
  
  for j in range(len(row)):
    column = row[j]
    if(len(str(column)) == 1):
      new_row.insert(len(new_row), 0)
      new_row.insert(len(new_row), column)
    else:
      new_row.insert(len(new_row), int(str(column)[0]))
      new_row.insert(len(new_row), int(str(column)[1]))
  
  m2.insert(len(new_row),new_row)
  
print(m2)
```

Comment: yup it works perfectly but can you show me another way i cant use those function for my assignment its forbidden can you maybe do that using basic python like for in range for example ?

Comment: updated solution - no append, list comprehension, no imported library. I hope it is ok now and every function is allowed - all are basic python :). I used range() but I think "for x in list/string/..." is good to know.